# How to fix Cannot GET / in Angular when refreshing the page?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I'm new in the Angular world. I followed Angular.io guide for routing my application and its many pages. The issue I have is when I hit the refresh button in the browser. I a "Cannot GET /dashboard" I have been researching about this issue and I do have the href="/" in placed.

This is my routing file

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
      {
        enableTracing: false
      }
    )],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

As mentioned before, I can get to the url but when I refresh the page I get the "Cannot GET /dashboard" Is there anything special I need to do to fix this issue? How to fix Cannot GET / in Angular when refreshing the page?

Comment: Is your server set up so that it returns the base HTML page no matter the URL? If not, when you go directly to `/dashboard` your server will think you're asking it for a dashboard page. But really you want the server to return the base HTML page, so the client side router can see `/dashboard` and take it from there. You could also switch to hash based routes to avoid this problem.

Comment: I'm hosting it on a IIS server and I have the index.html as default @FrankModica

Comment: You might need URL rewrites. Check out https://blog.angularindepth.com/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7

Comment: @FrankModica can you make that as an answer so you can get the points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server needs to be set up to return the base HTML page no matter the URL, so the client side router can then see `/dashboard` and take it from there. Otherwise, when you go directly to `/dashboard` your server will think you're asking it for a dashboard page.

You could accomplish this in IIS using URL rewrites. Here's an example from https://blog.angularindepth.com/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Another option is hash-based URLs, which can be accomplished like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

This works because the server doesn't see the hash portion of the URL. See https://angular.io/guide/router for details.

Answer (score 0):

I use Nodejs to serve angular files then I have added the following code part to `serve.js` then it was worked.

```js
app.route('/*').get(function (req, res) {
  return res.sendFile(path.join(staticRoot + 'index.html'));
});
```

[I get this content from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521443/angular-cannot-get-route-on-page-refresh)

If you use **Nginx** or **Apache** to serve files you have to use URLRewrite to redirect to the index.html. The server redirects the client to index.html and it will imports Angular and RoutingModule handles the navigation.

My `serve.js` content is:

```js
// index.html and its contents are inside the `html` folder
// and the server.js is located on the same path as the `html` folder.
var express = require('express'),
  path = require('path'),
  fs = require('fs');
var compression = require('compression');
var app = express();
var staticRoot = __dirname + '/html/';
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3002));

app.use(compression());
/* other middleware */

/* place any backend routes you have here */

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  //if the request is not html then move along
  var accept = req.accepts('html', 'json', 'xml');
  if (accept !== 'html') {
    return next();
  }
  // if the request has a '.' assume that it's for a file, move along
  var ext = path.extname(req.path);
  if (ext !== '') {
    return next();
  }
  fs.createReadStream(staticRoot + 'index.html').pipe(res);
});

app.use(express.static(staticRoot));

/**
* Redirect to index.html
*/
app.route('/*').get(function (req, res) {
  return res.sendFile(path.join(staticRoot + 'index.html'));
});


app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('app running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```