# Serve Angular client and Express Sever on IIS without breaking urls

Tags: node.js, angular, express, iis

I used `angular` on the client-side, and `nodejs` on server-side, when running them using `webstorm` IDE they behave as expected but now I'm trying to put them on is and I'm encountering some troubles.

**My main goal is to make just the client and server work together so if you have another suggestion which I have not tried, please comment.**

In the `IIS` I had to put both server and client under the same URL (obviously) so I have deployed my angular app and copied the content of the `dist` folder into folder name `"wwwroot`" to my server (`express`).

Here is my code:
`app.js` files:

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/wwwroot'));

app.post('/home', (req, res) => {

// some content here
});

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
 
// some content here
});

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => console.log('Listening to port: ' + port));
```

my `web.config` file:

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />         
        </handlers>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
                        <rule name="nodejs">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                            <conditions>
                                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                            </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="/app.js" />
                     </rule>
                 </rules>
            </rewrite> 

            <security>
                <requestFiltering>
                     <hiddenSegments>
                            <add segment="node_modules" />
                            <add segment="iisnode" />
                     </hiddenSegments>
                 </requestFiltering>
            </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now, it would work just fine but I have 1 main problem which I can't solve when I'm trying to reload a page via a `URL`,

e.g. "http://www.automationcompare.com:4040/home;urlId=23119.06799149191"
then I get: Cannot GET /home;urlId=23119.06799149191.

Comment: Edit your question to change the ALL CAPS section please, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121301/block-questions-in-all-caps

Answer (score 0):

I think the server should be set up to return the base HTML page no matter the url. You need to use url rewrite rule like below sample:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

For further information about your problem, you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332757/how-to-fix-cannot-get-in-angular-when-refreshing-the-page). I think it is similar to your problem.